# Universal links not working in iOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I have used uni_links plugin for applinking in android and iOS. In android it's working perfectly but in iOS not getting option to open url in app. I have put apple-app-site-association.json file inside .well-known folder as well as root folder.

**apple-app-site-association.json File:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.40.0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime
Content-Length: 245

{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "[TEAM_ID].[APP_BUNDLE_ID]",
        "paths": [ "*" ],
                "appIDs": ["[TEAM_ID].[APP_BUNDLE_ID]"],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have added my domain "applinks:myhost" in Runner.entitlements file and also enable FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled in info.plist. I have validate my apple-app-site-association.json file with branch.io and got below result:

[branch.io Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBkx6.png)

If anyone know the solution please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Try stackover flow solutions for 'content-type' error showing while validating on branch.io and also tried app_links plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by removing .json from apple-app-site-association.json file uploaded at server. It was such a small mistake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).